# re.search returns none for a pattern, but with a subpattern we get a result

Tags: python

We have the following:

```
string = "Your Policy gives you 18/11/21 (Noor) to 18/11/22 (Noon) 18/11/22 Comprehensive cover Sections AB,C,D,E,FGJ in your Policy booklet are the "

re.search('18/11/21 (Noor) to',string).span()
```

This return none type..

If I run `re.search('18/11/21',string).span()` then I get a result.
Why does this happen?

Comment: Parentheses in a regular expression are special: they indicate a capture pattern. You'll have to escape them: `re.search('18/11/21 \(Noor\) to',string).span()`.

Comment: Better yet: `'18/11/21 (Noor) to' in string` simply yields `True`, and `string.index('18/11/21 (Noor) to')` will give you the starting index in `string` of the pattern. As long as your pattern is a simple string, there is generally no need for a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses in a regular expression are special: they indicate a capture pattern. You'll have to escape them:

```
>>> re.search('18/11/21 \(Noor\) to',string).span()
(22, 40)
```

Better yet:

```
>>> '18/11/21 (Noor) to' in string
True
```

simply yields `True`, and

```
>>> string.index('18/11/21 (Noor) to')
22
```

will give you the starting index in `string` of the pattern. Combine with `len('18/11/21 (Noor) to')` to obtain the span.

As long as your pattern is a simple string, there is generally no need for a regular expression.

Comment: Many thanks user @9769953 ;)

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

> (...) Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses,
> and indicates the start and end of a group; the contents of a group
> can be retrieved after a match has been performed, and can be matched
> later in the string with the \number special sequence, described
> below. To match the literals '(' or ')', use \( or \), or enclose them
> inside a character class: [(], [)].

You need to escape

```py
string = "Your Policy gives you 18/11/21 (Noor) to 18/11/22 (Noon) 18/11/22 Comprehensive cover Sections AB,C,D,E,FGJ in your Policy booklet are the "

re.search('18/11/21 \(Noor\) to',string).span()
```